# What is the best way to use dplyr instead of a for-loop to do a vector index based subtraction from a data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, group

Here is an example data set (real data set is much bigger and with more rows):

```
 sample_df <- as.data.frame(cbind( 'group'=
    c('ABC123','ABC123','ABC123','ABC123','ABC123',
    'ABC111','ABC111','ABC111','ABC111',
    'ABC222','ABC222','ABC222','ABC222'),  
'value' = c(12345, 13334,
    12350, 13320, 12344, 12222, 12322, 12244,12344, 12315, 12333, 12305,
    12365), 
datetime = c("2000-01-01 23:50:00",
    "2000-01-01 23:51:00","2000-01-01 23:52:00","2000-01-01 23:53:30","2000-01-01 23:54:00",
    "2000-01-01 21:00:00","2000-01-01 21:10:00","2000-01-01 21:30:00","2000-01-01 22:00:00",
    "2000-01-01 03:00:02","2000-01-01 03:01:00","2000-01-01 03:02:10","2000-01-01 03:03:00")))

sample_df$value    <- as.numeric(sample_df$value)

# this is doing some stupid time conversion to the year but thats irrelevant here in the example: 
sample_df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(sample_df$value)
```

Im using the find_peaks() function from https://github.com/stas-g/findPeaks [Ref](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22974/how-to-find-local-peaks-valleys-in-a-series-of-data?newreg=c8ea99a73c204b8387a902e964fd24dd)

```
# Resulting list of vector indices of peaks and valleys (real list is much much larger) by group

 peak_index1 <-lapply(split(sample_df$value, sample_df$group),
 find_peaks, m = 1)  
valley_index1 <-lapply(split(-sample_df$value,
 sample_df$group), find_peaks, m = 1)
```

**This is where I'm stuck with the grouping variable.**

edit: I mean, I can get to the point of filling in a df with padded NAs to prevent recycling of shorter vectors when they arent the same length as the longest vector, but still have the same issue.

```
# find length of longest vector to pad NAs so cbind/rbind doesnt recycle shorter vector data
  how_long_p <-  which.max(lengths(peak_index))
  how_long_p <- length(peak_index[[how_long_p]])
# Makes it into a data frame without repeating shorter vectors, and fills in NAs
  peak_index <-sapply(peak_index, '[', 1:how_long_p)

# find length of longest vector to pad NAs so cbind/rbind doesnt recycle shorter vector data
    how_long_v <-  which.max(lengths(valley_index))
    how_long_v <- length(valley_index[[how_long_v]])
 # Makes it into a data frame without repeating shorter vectors, and fills in NAs
    valley_index <-sapply(valley_index, '[', 1:how_long_v)
```

Ok so if I was just looking at a single vector for one grouping variable, say ABC123,
then its an easy calculation:

```
# filtering to demonstrate single grouped variable procedure
subset <- sample_df %>% filter(group == 'ABC123')

q <- find_peaks(subset$value, m = 1) # peak indicies
r <- find_peaks(-subset$value, m = 1) # valley indicies

  # make vectors the same length for subtraction if needed (needed for the larger df)
  q <- q[1:min(length(q),length(r))]
  r <- r[1:min(length(q),length(r))]

  diff <- abs(subset$datetime[q] - subset$datetime[r])
  diff <- diff %>% as.data.frame()
```

So I need to be able to do that via group in a larger data frame, and while I can do it for a single group variable, Im struggling to do it with a larger df and many grouping variable entries. Any help would be appreciated.

edit:  Desired output is to be able to subtract the time differences between the peaks and valley times per grouping variable. So I'm stumped at how to manage this as its more complicated than just having one grouping variable.

I think the best situation would be a df with either col name or row1 being the identifying grouping variable. So each column by the grouping variable with the subtracted times as rows going downward (different grouping variables will have different lengths bc of the different sizes of the subtracted vectors). Or if there's a better way to manage it Im open to suggestion. Such as doing a wide vs long table somehow if that makes more sense?

```
sample_output <- as.data.frame(cbind( "ABC123"= c("16.400 mins","16.167 mins"),  
                                      "ABC111" = c("1.3 mins", NA), 
                                       "ABC222" = c("28 secs", NA)))
```

Comment: What is your desired output from your sample data?

Comment: @jpsmith I think the best situation would be a df with row1 being grouping variable. So each column by the grouping variable with the subtracted times as rows going downward (different grouping variables will have different lengths bc of the different sizes of the subtracted vectors). Or if there's a better way to manage it Im open to suggestion.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show your desired output?

Comment: done, thank you